# Camera and Music does not open in Android Pixel

Tags: android, camera, custom-rom, android-rom

I have compiled the android OS from the AOSP source code (7.1) and flashed the image on to the google Pixel device. I was successful in flashing the image but the camera and music do not seem to work. On clicking on the camera it shows "Camera error can't connect to the camera". Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: This is the bug since android 5.0. it occurs when the app using camera(eg. Snapchat) does not release the camera after they are done. You can solve it by rebooting or uncheck permission of apps except google camera in setting>apps>permission>camera (something like this). If rebooting does not solve it, it is hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Get the logcat and see what the exact problem is. You can refer [this guide on XDA-developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238) to get the logcat.